# ArcGIS Pro Error 00221 - How to limit number of features?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, web-scene

I have just tried to create my first web scene using ArcGIS Pro but upon sharing I receive the error **00221: Feature layer is displaying more than 2000 features**.

I also tried to directly make the scene through ArcGIS Online and I received the same error.

My research took me to [this page](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/sharing/analyzer-error-messages/00221-feature-layer-is-displaying-more-than-2000-features.htm)  which suggested creating a definition query but this is where I am stuck (my SQL skills are still beginning).

- How do I create a definition query that will select 2000 depending on location?
- How does everyone else get past this when displaying city data?  Are there any alternatives?

Comment: We are working on improving the way features are requested in the 4.x JS API so this feature limit will improve to query features by the extent you are viewing.
If you are using points, you could make them into multipatches and then cook them in the Create Scene Layer Package tool in pro which will create a cache of all the features. This tool right now will only output in WGS84 but the next release will support other coordinate systems and also non-multipatch features. But once you get the output, upload it to AGOL, this creates a hosted scene layer which can be used in scene viewer.

Comment: Hi @RussRoberts I was using polygons and the z value was an equation of another field.  I have now created the same data into a points feature class.  Can you please expand on how to make a multipatch, this is not something I have come across before.

Comment: So for your polygons that are extruded - use the Layer 3D to Feature Class tool. This will create a multipatch. Then use the Create Scene Layer Package tool to create the .spk which you will upload to AGOL. The scene layer will have a cache of the 3D features and the attributes. For points you can try the buffer 3D tool, then use the output in the Create Scene Layer package tool.

Comment: Thanks @RussRoberts that seems to have done the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Russ Roberts suggested: -

"So for your polygons that are extruded - use the Layer 3D to Feature Class tool. This will create a multipatch. Then use the Create Scene Layer Package tool to create the .spk which you will upload to AGOL. The scene layer will have a cache of the 3D features and the attributes. For points you can try the buffer 3D tool, then use the output in the Create Scene Layer package tool."

This achieved the results I was after.